# Facebook.getLoginStatus not calling it's call back

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

```
    public function getLoginStatus(callback:Function) {
        Facebook.addJSEventListener("auth.sessionChange", callback)

        setTimeout(Facebook.getLoginStatus, 1200);
    }
```

I tried both with delay and without delay

and my callback function looks like this,

```
    public function getLoginStatusHandler(result:Object):void {
        trace('success');
    }
```

and call to the function is

```
getLoginStatus(getLoginStatusHandler);
```

application has been initialized properly

I believe for my html page, i need only this for FB to work properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: You say you are initializing the application, but are you initializing the Facebook object via Facebook.init()?

Comment: yes through Facebook.init() right in the beginning (on load), and I get init success, (application initialized as well as authenticated), the getLoginStatus is called on user click.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not really familiar with ActionScript – but in JavaScript calling the Facebook.getLoginStatus method with setTimeout would take it out of the actual context. Is there a reason why you are not calling Facebook.getLoginStatus directly?

Comment: that's correct, it happens in javascript, my Facebook functions are organized in a class, that's why calling from outside but I just tested one with direct inline implementation but still no success

Comment: tested without setTimeout as well, :(